# Hacked database by using mongodb. Did anyone get this situation?

Tags: mongodb

Today, my website suddenly down and then I checked my database which I used mongodb. It seemed that someone hacked my database and then they created a collection like this:

```html
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e3dd717e3d0c9664c95ad51"
    },
    "btc": "1J7YbJbvmPBXZsR4U8dGbhDC7WH5EwoRQt",
    "info": "All your data is a backed up. You must pay 0.1 BTC to 1J7YbJbvmPBXZsR4U8dGbhDC7WH5EwoRQt 48 hours for recover it. 
    After 48 hours expiration we will leaked and exposed all your data. Also do not forget about GDPR. 
    Need any proofs? coojeipo@secmail.pro You are welcome!"
}
```

I don't know what should I do now. Do I need to uninstall mongodb on my server and then setup it again? Please give my advice.

Thank you

Comment: As it's already got hacked, your data might probably be with them, you need to report this incident first, If you've backup & your current DB deployment is weak, create another instance at another server & import data. Did you restrict DB access to certain IP ranges where you/your teammates & app uses ? If you're not able to maintain DB try **MongoDB Atlas** supported by MongoDB itself they'll do all maintenance & secured hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, such attacks were carried out in 2017 as well. The attackers simply scan entire IPv4 internet for a MongoDB running on port 271017.

You need at least user authentication to stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

use MongoDB [atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) for production and make sure you set your server application IP address as the only IP address that can access your application.